# Firefox 27 wants to use HTTPS everywhere

Tags: firefox, https, https-everywhere

I've got a weird problem with my Firefox 27.0.1: *Literally any webpage* I want to visit is automatically requested via HTTPS, and that means I constantly get "Untrusted Connection" warnings - see first image below.

I am forced to either give up or accept a certificate exception for the site (see second image below). As a workaround, I can add an exception manually but this gets tedious real quick, because it needs to be done for *every* site I visit.

**What is causing this annoying behavior,** if it's not the *HTTPS Everywhere* plugin?

I had the *HTTPS Everywhere* plugin installed and I disabled that - it didn't solve the problem so I uninstalled it instead. That still has not solved the problem. Could it be something about the corporate firewall that has been changed?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you disable it or uninstall it? Does the same issue occur in IE or in FireFox when in safe mode?

Comment: I only disabled it, and even rebooted. I've now really uninstalled it and restarted Firefox - and the problem is gone. ("WTF?")

Comment: After uninstalling HTTPS-everywhere the problem seemed to be gone, but it's not. Something else is causing this problem.